# How to make a moss pole with stuff other than moss?

Tags: container-gardening, tools

I have bamboo sticks which I want to use for my climbing aroids.

**The moss** - absorbs more water than peat and is a good medium for aerial roots. It is, however, hard to find in my area, so I must find something else.

**Alternatives** - What about rockwool, sawdust, sponge, old cloth? Sawdust is harder to tie to a pole without a net, so this is a last resort solution. Also, constantly looking for old sockings and pantyhose to contain the sawdust is not practical and may appear kinky to others. I prefer my poles be built out of standard materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a moss stick or moss pole is to push the aerial roots into it as they grow, so they can collect moisture if they want. Home made ones are usually made using wire mesh, filled with sphagnum moss - it sounds like you're thinking of somehow trying to wrap something round a bamboo stick instead. Using sponge or rockwool will not only be hard to wrap round a stick, it will look unsightly and be pretty useless for the aerial roots.

Sphagnum moss can be ordered online - a small bag will swell sufficiently when soaked in water to at least double or triple in size. Some instructions here on how to make a moss pole https://garden.org/ideas/view/threegardeners/881/Make-Your-Own-Moss-Pole/